# Why is this ENTRYPOINT incorrect?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker

My `DockerFile` has an `ENTRYPOINT` that just echoes `ENTRYPOINT echo %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd` to the command window.

- This syntax works:  `ENTRYPOINT echo %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd`
- This doesn't:  `ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd"]`

The output is `'[\"echo\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What's the different between these two syntaxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) (who'd have thought that?)

The first form executes in a shell, and is therefore equivalent to anything you might type into it.

The second form doesn't execute in a shell, it just executes the file with the provided arguments.

Comment: The message is a little misleading, because it includes the leading `[\"` and trailing `\"`. I encountered this, and thought I had a syntax error in the Dockerfile. It gives this message when the first item in the `ENTRYPOINT` array cannot be found in `PATH`